# Hide div when clicking wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
var x = 0;
if (x == 0) {
    $('#tap').click(function() {
        $('#menuUser').show();
    });
    x = 1;
    document.getElementById('var').innerHTML = "" + x + "";
}
else if (x == 1) {
    $('.#wpId').click(function() {
        $('#menuUser').hide();
    });
    x = 0;
}
```

I use that to hide `#menuUser` if `x=1`, but it didn't work.

Comment: $('.#wpId')? id and class?

Comment: why are you using `getElementById` when you have jQuery loaded?

Comment: You are just setting handler to some events and NOT executing them!

Comment: no it just my wrong typing when i ask this question, it's just id

Comment: illa choly: i want to check var x

Comment: You don't need `"" + x + "";`, it can just be `x;`

Comment: So when `$('#wpId')` is clicked, `$('#menuUser')` remains visible? Have you tried debugging in Firebug? Adding an `alert` or `console.log()`?

Comment: You know that you are attaching the event handlers on every check of `x`, right? You don't need the `x` part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the event handlers on DOM `ready` like below:

```
$(function () {
    var x = 0;

    $('#wpId').click(function () {
        $('#menuUser').hide();
        //if x is needed for something else
        x = 0;
        $('#var').text(x);
    });


    $('#tap').click(function (ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        $('#menuUser').show();
        //if x is needed for something else
        x = 1;
        $('#var').text(x);
    });
});
```

You can test it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/csicky/A7p37/1/

Comment: #wpId is wrapper and #tap is within it, so if i click tap , i also click wpId

Comment: @user2924643 You forgot to mention that. Updated the answer.